# How to use purrr and rvest in R to scrape transcripts from a webpage?

Tags: r, web-scraping, purrr, rvest

I am trying to extract all transcripts available on this [webpage](http://kremlin.ru/events/president/transcripts). I have been able to successfully extract the dates and titles of the speeches using the following code in `R`:

```
library(purr)
library(rvest)

url_kremlin <- "http://kremlin.ru/events/president/transcripts/page/"

map(1:10, safely(function(i) {
  pg <- read_html(paste0(url_kremlin, i))
  
  data.frame(date = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".dt-published")),
             title = html_text(html_nodes(pg, ".p-name")),
             link = html_nodes(pg, ".p-name") %>%
             html_node("p") %>% html_attr("href"))
})) -> kremlin_df
```

I am unable to extract the text of the transcripts, though. Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? What could should I use to successfully extract the transcripts?

Edit: When I run the code above, this is what I get: [image]. The `link` should contain the text of the speeches (or at least that's what I want it to contain).

Comment: What exactly are you trying to extract ? Every page has links to other articles. Those articles are loaded dynamically. Do you want to extract text from those articles?

Comment: Yes, I would like to extract the text from those pages.

Comment: I've added more information to the original post. Any help would be appreciated.